# Student registered in some n team show colorful grid indicating presence or absence of clash between each team

Tags: python, compare, read.csv

Input: Student registered in some 'n' teams.

Output: Colourful grid indicating presense or absence of clash between each team.

I tried to solve this on jupyter notebook editor

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv ('mini-project1.csv')

matched_values = df['Team A'][df['Team A']==df['Team B']].values

print(matched_values)
```

but how to show the colorfull grid indicating presense or absence of clash between each team.